# Should a business testimonial advertisement without any contact information be used "as is" in a publication?

Tags: business, consumer-protection, media

A testimonial advertisement was provided by a business (for their own endorsement) in a publication. Traditionally, print advertisements may need some sort of visual text contact information to be included to be considered and viewed as an "advertisement"? If contact information or a call to action is not used, would this testimonial ad be considered/viewed as editorial in the publication?

Comment: (1) The question in the title seems opinion-based and, given the current [lack of] detail in your post, unanswerable from a legal standpoint.  (2) The statement that begins with "*Traditionally*" ends with a question mark. Are you asking for confirmation? If so, be mindful that that is not a question that can be answered with a rationale about law. If it is actually not a question, you might want to provide sources that reflect from a legal standpoint the relevance of that remark. (3) What do you mean by "*as editorial in the publication*"?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no **legal** requirement that an advertisement include contact info for the firm whose goods are being promoted. Certainly  such a requirement is not present in **all** possible jurisdictions. If the publication is concerned that the offered composition (text plus any images) would look like an editorial endorsement, they could simply place a tag such as "paid advertisement" over or adjacent to the composition. (I have seen this done in various publications.) Or they could require addition of the advertiser's name and contact info before they accept they ad. This would be a matter of the publication's policies and business judgement. I do not believe it would be a matter of a legal requirement in the US at least, and I have not heard of any jurisdiction where it would be.